# Is it advisable to follow up journal editor for knowing the status of the manuscript submitted?

Tags: publications, publishers

I submitted a manuscript to one of a popular Indian civil engineering journal 6 months back. They haven't given any comments yet. Is it advisable to follow up them via. mail.?

Comment: This question has been asked in various guises a lot. The short answer is "yes". If you hear nothing at all after confirmation of submission, ~1 month should be enough to ask for a status update.

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can. but do not over do it. and pls note the editor is not bound to reply. he may do so courteously. but instead of 1 month blank, find the average time cycle for that journal (every journal has different response times) and wait twice or thrice the same. some journals have query/ redressal links; pls use them before email. use email as last resort